# Getting first app to work - Nativescript w/ Angular2

Tags: nativescript

I was able to complete the groceries tutorial.

I'm trying to get my first app to work - it's not working right now.

I noticed that my project creates .map files for all the ts/js files - the groceries tutorial doesn't.

e.g. main.js.map app.routes.js.map etc and also for my components - generated during a build.

Anyone know why my project has it and not the groceries tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your `tsconfig.json` in the project and ensure this is set:
`"sourceMap": false`

That should prevent source map files from being generated.
Often when you setup a new TypeScript project, the default `tsconfig.json` can have that set to `true` initially.

You will then likely need to go and cleanup (remove) those `.map` files if you want them out of your project.

Additionally, you mentioned your app was not working. What about your app is not working, please include the specific error and stack trace you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks - that worked!  

On a related note - i'm using VS Code editor - is there a way to tell it not to display the .js files (because they're generated by the .ts files).

Comment: Re the problem - trying to display a page and it's not using the html layout file.  I'm using router and it calls the .ts file ngOnInit(). In that file, I have the Component structure defined with templateUrl pointed to the html file. I don't get a file-not-found.<br/>`@Component({
  selector: "listview",
  templateUrl: "pages/listview/listview.html",
  styleUrls:  ["pages/listview/listview-common.css"]
})`

Here's the html file  

`<Label text="Tap the button" class="title"></Label>`

Comment: I'm trying to put in line breaks. <br/> or space-space ENTER - both didn't work. Help a newbie here!

Comment: I got it to work. I had this for compenent definition `@Component({
  selector: "listview",
  template:`<Label text="Tap the button" class="title"></Label>`
})`. As soon as I changed the selector to "list" - it worked. The only place where I think that would be referenced is in the RouterConfig path attribute...over there I have a blank string - which I assume means default path. Why would "list" work and not "listview"?

Comment: I changed the selector to a random string and that works also - just not listview. listview happens to be the name of the file - /pages/listview/listview.ts. Apologies for the formatting and multiple entries. Trying to get this stackoverflow thing down.